# Go matrix mutating when adding column

Tags: go

I'm writing a card game with go. I have the in-play cards in a slice matrix (3 rows, n columns) and the cards in the deck in a normal slice

```
type Game struct {
    Deck     []Card   `json:"-"`
    InPlay   [][]Card `json:"in_play,omitempty"`
}

type Card struct {
    Number  *int64 `json:"number"`
    Suit    *int64 `json:"suit"`
}
```

In a certain situation, I want to add another row of cards by

```
func(g *Game) AddCards() {
  g.InPlay[0] = append(g.InPlay[0], g.Deck[0])
  g.InPlay[1] = append(g.InPlay[1], g.Deck[1])
  g.InPlay[2] = append(g.InPlay[2], g.Deck[2])
  g.Deck = g.Deck[3:]
}
```

Instead of adding a new column of cards, this ends up adding the column, but also mutating the cards I have in-play.

```
1 4 7            1  4 7 10              1 4 7 10
2 5 8   becomes  10 5 8 11  instead of  2 5 8 11
3 6 9            11 6 9 12              3 6 9 12
```

strangely it follows this pattern if I add another column

```
1  4 7 10            1  4  7 10 13              1  4 7 10 13
10 5 8 11   becomes  10 13 8 11 14  instead of  10 5 8 11 14
11 6 9 12            11 14 9 12 15              11 6 9 12 15
```

It only happens to the bottom to cards in a column, 3 columns left of where the new column is added

EDIT

The deck is created with

```
func New() *Deck {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    deck := Deck{}
    cards := []Card{}

    // Constant integers
    for _, number := range NUMBERS {
        for _, suit := range SUITS {
            card := Card{
                Number:  ptr.int64(number), // turns int64 to pointer
                Suit: ptr.int64(suit),
            }
            cards = append(cards, card)
        }
    }

    deck.Cards = cards
    deck.Shuffle()
    return &deck
}
```

and the initial matrix is made with

```
func (g *Game) Deal() {
    inPlay := [][]deck.Card{[]deck.Card{}, []deck.Card{}, []deck.Card{}}
    inPlay[0] = g.Deck.Cards[0:4]
    inPlay[1] = g.Deck.Cards[4:8]
    inPlay[2] = g.Deck.Cards[8:12]

    g.InPlay = inPlay
    g.Deck.Cards = g.Deck.Cards[12:]
    return
}
```

Comment: How `g.InPlay[0]`, `g.InPlay[1]`, and `g.InPlay[2]` were created? Are you sure they don't share the same underlying array?

Comment: So - this is the problem: `inPlay[0] = g.Deck.Cards[0:4]
    inPlay[1] = g.Deck.Cards[4:8]
    inPlay[2] = g.Deck.Cards[8:12]` --- you create them with the same underlying array. If you want to change their lengths - you must create separate independent slices.

Comment: What would the proper way to initialize the in-play cards?

Comment: "proper way to initialize the in-play cards" --- who knows - we have no idea about the design of your application. One thing is certain though: if you want to change the length of slices - they must be independent slices with its own backing internal array.

Comment: If I have an array with all of my cards, and I want to take the first 9 cards of the array, what's a way I can do it that will avoid mutation later. It seems like there should be an answer that's independent of my specific application?

Comment: "If I have an array with all of my cards, and I want to take the first 9 cards of the array" --- you physically pop it from one slice and put into another. The card deck and every player hands - are different independent collections (like in real life).

Comment: what's the way to copy a slice so it won't reference g.Deck.Cards anymore?

Comment: Have you tried to search for `go copy slice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

```golang
func(c *Card) Copy() *Card {
  return &Card{
    Number: c.Number,
    Suit: c.Suit,
  }
}
```

```golang
func(g *Game) AddCards() {
  g.InPlay[0] = append(g.InPlay[0], g.Deck[0].Copy())
  g.InPlay[1] = append(g.InPlay[1], g.Deck[1].Copy())
  g.InPlay[2] = append(g.InPlay[2], g.Deck[2].Copy())
  g.Deck = g.Deck[3:]
}
```

```golang
func (g *Game) Deal() {
  inPlay := [][]deck.Card{[]deck.Card{}, []deck.Card{}, []deck.Card{}}
  for i, row := range inPlay {
    for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
      row = append(row, g.Deck.Cards[j].Copy())
    }
    g.Deck.Cards = g.Deck.Cards[3:]
  }
  g.InPlay = inPlay
  return
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `g.InPlay` slices share the underlying array, and items of `g.Deck` are `Card`, not `*Card`

Comment: Fixed. Suggest commenting/answering with solutions rather than just pointing out problems.

Comment: "rather than just pointing out problems" --- I have already answered the question in comments 25 minutes ago, not sure what you mean by that. Your solution masks the problem, does not solve its original roots.

Comment: @SpencerConnaughton this solution works. Thanks for the help :D